# Make meter in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, cpu-usage, meter

I'm newbie and i'm making small application for Android. I would like to display a meter to show CPU usage.
I already get CPU usage but do NOT know how to make the meter like that: http://vb2.upanh.com/thumbpic/22.878.29891111.asR0/capture.700x0.jpg

Somebody help me! Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

GeekYouUp's Battery Widget includes a simple example of creating a graph/meter somewhat similar to the example posted.  It's code and graphics are available at code.google.com/p/batterywidget/

Where will is the meter graphic to appear?  On a main activity screen?  In the taskbar?  In an app widget?  Live wallpaper?

Comment: i want the meter appear on main activity. I read  that example but not really understand... Can u list for me steps to make it? (I already have a variable get cpu usage once time/second).